How to 'Group By' a value that is not constant?
Scenario: I need to make a query to show the most recent value($) for all of my items. Note, the value of these items changes over time, so I would like to see what the most current value is for that item. I have simplified my tables for this example, but basically I have the below 3 tables I need to use for this query:
Table 1:(This table is simply to get the ITEM_name based on it's ID)



ITEM_ID
ITEM_Name




101
Painting1


102
Painting2


103
Painting3



Table 2: (this table reflects the price of an item and tracks how the value of that items changes over time)



ITEM_ID
Start_Date
End_Date
Item_Value($)




101
01/1960
12/2022
2.75


101
01/2022
12/2023
3.35


102
1/2023
11/2024
8.99



Table 3: (This table contains additional information on my items that I would like in my final output)



ITEM_ID
ITEM_Owner
ITEM_condition




101
John
fair


102
Taylor
good



Expected Results: As my end result, I would like to see the item name along with its most current value we have on record (Note, I am filtering by the max end date to get the most current item value)



ITEM_Name
Max(End_Date)
Item_Value($)
ITEM_Owner




101
12/2023
3.35
John


102
11/2024
8.99
Taylor



Below Query Result:(the 2nd record should not show in my final output)



ITEM_Name
Max(End_Date)
Item_Value($)
ITEM_Owner




101
12/2023
3.35
John


101
12/2022
2.75
John


102
11/2024
8.99
Taylor



My Query:
select M.ITEM_Name,MAX(MMM.End_Date), MMM.Item_Value($),MM.ITEM_Owner
FROM Table_3 MM
    INNER JOIN Table_1 M ON M.ITEM_ID = MM.ITEM_ID
    INNER JOIN Table_2 MMM ON MMM.ITEM_ID = MM.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY M.ITEM_Name,MAX(MMM.End_Date), MMM.Item_Value($),MM.ITEM_Owner;

From my understanding, there is an issue with my group by clause.It is trying to group by Item_Value($) column as well, even though those are not constant values. I need my result to only show the Item_Value($) for the Max end date, and not both end dates. Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

For the future: Giving your tables generic names like table_1, table2, etc. only makes it more difficult for us to follow. Same for alias names. Better use meaningful names like item and price and mnemonic aliases like i for item right away.

Yes very obviously there is an issue with your GROUP BY clause. With GROUP BY x, y, z you say you want one result row for each x, y, z. You want one result row per item, so GROUP BY item_id or GROUP BY item_name.
If you GROUP BY m.item_name, mmm.item_value, then you get one row for each item and price naturally. And you cannot GROUP BY MAX(mmm.end_date), because MAX(mmm.end_date) is the maximum end date for the group you state in GROUP BY. You cannot say give me the maximum date for the maximum date; it just makes no sense.
Your sample data seems incorrect, too, because for item 101 you have two overlapping ranges, which would mean that in 06/2022 for instance the item had two different prices at the same time. Or do you want to allow multiple prices for a period and show them all in your results, then?
Well, as you want the row with the greatest end date anyway (so you don't expect future entries in the table or you don't care that you may sjhow future prices instead of current ones), this won't be an issue here. You could use Oracle's KEEP LAST to get an item's last price, or better yet, use either a window function or a lateral join.
You have three tables

table 1, which contains one row per item, so I am calling this the item table.
table 2, which contains the prices with one row per item and time range, so I am calling this the price table.
table 3, which seems to contain one row per item, too, so I wonder why this is a separate table at all. Why don't you store the information in the item table? Well, I am calling this the item_plus table.

The lateral join solution (CROSS APPLY):
SELECT
  i.item_name,
  lp.end_date,
  lp.item_value,
  ip.item_owner
FROM item i
INNER JOIN item_plus ip ON ip.item_id = i.item_id
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT *
  FROM price p
  WHERE p.item_id = i.item_id
  ORDER BY p.end_date DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) lp
ORDER BY i.item_name;

If you want a solution with a window function, look for similar requests in stackoverflow. You'd want MAX(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id) or use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY end_date DESC).

Thank you, this is really helpful! I was able to get my desired result with that SQL. Appreciate the help and detailed explanation.

Use ROW_NUMBER to find the most recent value($) grouped by ITEM_ID
Query untested,
WITH latest_record AS (
            SELECT MM.ITEM_ID
                   MM.End_Date,
                   MM.Item_Value($),
                   MMM.ITEM_Owner,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MM.ITEM_ID ORDER BY End_Date DESC) rn
            FROM Table_2 MM
            INNER JOIN Table_3 MMM ON MMM.ITEM_ID = MM.ITEM_ID
) SELECT M.ITEM_Name,
         lr.End_Date,
         lr.Item_Value,
         lr.ITEM_Owner
  FROM latest_record lr 
  INNER JOIN Table_1 M on M.ITEM_ID = lr.ITEM_ID
  WHERE rn = 1;


Some flaws. You select table_2 twice and you don't select table_1. (@Almo: This is the problem with generic names; they just confuse us.) There is NNER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. The latest_record view doesn't contain the latest prices as the name suggests, but all prices, only numbered. So either change the name to something like numbered_rows, and then pick those with #1 later, or use an ORDER BY and FETCH FIRST combination to really only get the latest prices.

@ThorstenKettner those were all typos by me, I was in a hurry . Fixed NNER JOIN, the repeated  Table_2 name and added the WHERE rn = 1 , which was the whole point of the WITH clause. Thanks for pointing out

Thank you Ergest! Appreciate your help on this
